# Show only current Option value Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

when my function runs second time i get the values in the select as shown below:

[image: <code>Image</code>]

i.e: i am also getting the previous seleted option "Interest Bearing Checkings". I tried really hard but couln't solve this problem.

**code:**

```
$("select").each(function(i)
{
    var $el = $(this);
    var $options = $el.find("option:selected");

    var prevtext;

    var divlength = $('.print-select').length;
    if(divlength == 0)
    {
        $el.after("<select class='print-select' style='color: #2C2C2C; height:30px; width: 231px; margin-left: 409px'><option id=sel"+i+"></option></select>");   

        var $curPrintBox = $("#sel"+i);

        $options.each(function()
        {
            $curPrintBox.append($(this).text());

            prevtext = $(this).text();
            alert(prevtext);
        });

        return false;
    }

    if(divlength != 0)
    {alert("a");
        $el
        .find(prevtext)
        .empty()
        .append("<select class='print-select' selected='selected' style='color: #2C2C2C; height:30px; width: 231px; margin-left: 409px'><option>dssd</option></select>");
        ;

        var $curPrintBox = $("#sel"+i);

        $options.each(function()
        {
            $curPrintBox.append($(this).text());
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    }
});
```

**html:**

```
<select id="ChangeAccount" style="width: 231px">
                                    <option value="">Select Account Name</option>
                                    <option>Basic Checking</option>
                                    <option>Interest Bearing Checking</option>
                                    <option>Savings</option>
                                    <option>Certificate of Deposit (CD)</option>
                                    <option>Money Market Deposit (MMD)</option>
                                    <option>Individual Retirement (IR)</option>
                                    <option>Other</option>
                                </select>
```

Comment: can you show some markup or create a fiddle ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Current code is only copying the first `option` into another `select` on load.

Comment: @Batu Zet i am printing. when i click on print button a function called which contains this code. the function works fine for the first call but when i select another value from select and again click print function, i get the above result in the print.

Comment: Mate, it's really hard to understand what youre trying to do from your code. It seems like this could've be done with 4-5 lines of code. Please tell me what exactly are you expecting this code to do?

Comment: @Batu Zet hey plz help me. I just want to show a selected option on print preview. thats just i want.

Comment: this is i want http://css-tricks.com/examples/SelectPrintable/ just show the selected option value on print preview

Comment: heres the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2A4ud/1/ please solve this for me. if you click on the print 2 times then chk the results or after selecting another option then again clicked the print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your jquery code to show only selected option:

```
$("select#ChangeAccount").on("change", function(){

  var $option = $(this).find("option:selected");

  $(".print-select").remove();     

  $(this).after("<div class='print-select'>Selected Option: "+$option.text()+"</div>");  

});
```

But the trick lies another place: in styles. You can see in above code selected `option` is displayed inside a `div` which has a class `print-select`. So you just need to hide that div on `screen` style then show it on `print` style like:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  .print-select { 
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<style type="text/css" media="print">
  .print-select {
    display:block;
    /* and other props that you want that div to have like border, background... */
  }
</style>
```

Comment: can you tell me one thing more. if i have more than one `select` then how should i approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You almost doing it right. just replace the last lines like:

```
  $("select").each(function(i)
  {
 var $el = $(this);
 var $options = $el.find("option:selected");

var prevtext;

var divlength = $('.print-select').length;
if(divlength == 0)
{
    $el.after("<select class='print-select' style='color: #2C2C2C; height:30px; width: 231px; margin-left: 409px'><option id=sel"+i+"></option></select>");   

    var $curPrintBox = $("#sel"+i);

    $options.each(function()
    {
        $curPrintBox.append($(this).text());

        prevtext = $(this).text();
        alert(prevtext);
    });

    return false;
}

if(divlength != 0)
{alert("a");
    $el
    .find(prevtext)
    .empty()
    .append("<select class='print-select' selected='selected' style='color: #2C2C2C; height:30px; width: 231px; margin-left: 409px'><option>dssd</option></select>");
    ;

    var $curPrintBox = $("#sel"+i);

    $options.each(function()
     {
        $curPrintBox.parent().append("<option>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");//change this line
        alert($(this).text());
     });
 }
  });
```